# Stopping re-render with React.Memo does not work

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an issue with react re-rendering.

Basically, I have a list of 100 entries, which are in fact divs that contain further HTML elements. When changing one prop, which does not affect any of the entries, they all seem to re-render, causing some spikes or delay across the page.

```
const upperComponent = () => {
    ...some logic
    return (<ExampleList tabs={tabs} content={content}/>)
```

Tabs will change, but it does not affect the list of 100 entries, that will always be the same regardless of 'tabs

```
const exampleList = ({tabs, content}) => {
    ...some logic here with tabs
    ...return is unaffected by tabs
    return
     (<div....<div....<more divs and spans...)
```

Everytime tabs changes, the return is rendered, and it's something I want to avoid

I tried the following:

```
const exampleList = React.Memo(({tabs, content}) => {
    ...some logic here with tabs
    ...return is unaffected by tabs
    return
     (<div....<div....<more divs and spans...), function(prevProps, nextProps) {
    if (prevProps.content !== nextProps.content) return true
    return false
}
```

But it seems that the component will not render at all in this case

What am I even doing wrong?

Comment: at first line  parenthesis is opened `const exampleList = React.Memo(({tabs, content}) => {`, but never closed. What are the parameters passed to `React.Memo`?

Comment: Take a look at the doc https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo you'll find the second argument and it's usage.

Comment: is your `tabs` and `content` are nested object? or plain single level objects? @